# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'begin' in sybase

Tags: sybase

Here is my piece of code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
CREATE VIEW abl_uds_bod AS
     SELECT DISTINCT BOD_INTRMDTRY_ID, BOD_BROKERAGE
     FROM BOD_BNFC_OWNR_DTLS
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DISTINCT UDS_CA_ID, UDS_SEC_ID
     FROM UDS_UPLD_DSCLSR
     UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT ABL_ORDR_ID, ABL_ERR_DESC
      FROM ABL_ADD_BLK_LST
'
END
```

This is throwing error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'begin' ".
I have seen many people searching for the same problem but haven't got any satisfactory answer.

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1520/html/iqrefso/X315708.htm - parameters are optional, but not the parens that surround them.

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  Which Sybase database product are you referring to?  ASE, IQ, SQLAnywhere?  Tagging the question properly will help you get a faster, and more helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this s Sybase ASE, you are missing the AS keyword:

CREATE PROCEURE myproc
AS
BEGIN
....